# Need to process all files in a directory, but am only getting one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python script that is successfully processing single files. I am trying to write a `for` loop to have it get all the files in a directory that the user inputs. However, it is only processing one of the files in the directory.

The code below is followed by the rest of the script that does the analysis on `data`. Do I need to somehow close the `for` loop?

```
import os

print "Enter the location of the files: "; directory = raw_input()
path = r"%s" % directory

for file in os.listdir(path):
    current_file = os.path.join(path, file)

    data = open(current_file, "rb")

    # Here's an abridged version of the data analysis

    for i in range(0, 10):
        fluff = data.readline()

    Input_Parameters = fluff.split("\t")

    output.write("%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%.3f\t%.1f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%s\n" % (Voc, Isc, Vmp, Imp, Pmax, 100 * Eff, IscErr, 100 * (1 - (P2 / Pmax)), file))
    data.close()
```

Comment: Python indentation controls what is executed in the for loop...

Comment: Also, `path = r"%s" % directory` doesn't do anything particularly useful. (The `r` only applies to the string literal, and `r'%s'` is just `'%s'`.)

Comment: Sorry, the second for loop is indented in the code. When I copied it here it somehow removed the indentation.

Comment: @Ben, what happens if you just `print os.listdir(path)`?

Comment: Indentation error again? or are you really just needing the 10th line of the file for `Input_Parameters`?

Comment: For the record, `path = r"%s" % directory` is completely equivalent to `path = str(directory)`, but since directory is already guaranteed to be a string, it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @mgilson - It outputs a list of the filenames in the directory four times (and there are currently four files). So it looks like I'm handing it a list of all the files each time instead of a single filename?

Comment: @mgilson - The for loop creating fluff is my clumsy way of moving past the first 10 lines of irrelevant data. I know there's a more elegant way to do that but it's working right now and so I'm trying to figure out the parts that aren't working.

Comment: @Wooble & bukzor, I don't understand it but if I remove the r or change it to path = str(directory) I generate errors.

Comment: @Ben: No, you're just printing the whole `os.listdir(path)` list four times, once for each file. Change it to `print file, current_file` and make it the line after the assignment to `current_file` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @Ben: Your sample code doesn't appear to be using `Input_Parameters`.

Comment: @martineau, Thanks now it's printing each file and path/file just once

Comment: @martineau, Yeah I greatly abridged the data analysis. It works when I run it alone or in this case it executes on one file in the directory.

Comment: @Ben: In that case, your code looks OK and should process each of the four files. Of cource you realize it's writing to the same `output` file for all four of them.

Comment: @martineau, OK, that's it then . . . I'm overwriting the file each time. I should be able to figure that out.

Comment: Sweet, it's working now. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current code in your answer looks basically OK to me. I noticed that it's writing to the same `output` file for each of the files it processes, so that may lead you to think it's not processing them all.

Answer (score 7):

In general, if something does not work, you can try to get something simpler working. I removed the data analysis part and kept the code below. This works with me. I noticed that if I have a directory in my path, the open will fail. I am not sure this is the case with you as well.

```
import os
import sys

path = '.'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    current = os.path.join(path, file)
    if os.path.isfile(current):
        data = open(current, "rb")
        print len(data.read())
```

Comment: This is still giving me output from just one of the files. I put all the data anlaysis code where your print len(data) line is, within the if statement.

Comment: What happens if you _remove_ the data analysis code? This way you can determine if the problem is in your loop or in your analysis code. Also, do you see a stack trace or an error message?

Comment: This will give a `TypeError` (file objects have no `len`)

Answer (score 1):

for you debugging:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    current_file = os.path.join(path, file)
    print current_file
```

check the output of current_file

BTW: are you indent your code by tab?

because there are different indent length in your code.

**This is bad style**

Comment: That successfully prints all the files in the directory. But it still executes the analysis on just one.