# loading data from txt to python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, numpy

I have 100 text files in a folder that I wanna load into a list.
I was only able to load one file. how can I load all the files?
Here is what I did

```
with open('varmodel/varmodel_2.var') as f:
varmodel_2 = f.read()
print(varmodel_2)
```

However, instead of 2, I have from 1 to 100

Comment: What have you tried? Loops, blobs, dictionaries...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and explain *what the actual difficulty is*. Do you know how to repeat code? Do you know how to create the file names? If you repeat the code for each file name, does that solve the problem? Also, what does this question have to do with Pandas or Numpy?

Comment: Check out the existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497901/need-to-process-all-files-in-a-directory-but-am-only-getting-one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `glob` module to do just that. It gives you a list of all files/folders in a directory. Here is the code you would use to get a string containing all of the file information:

```
import glob

string = ""
for filename in glob.glob("*"):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        string += f.read()

print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    all_files = []
    for dir in glob.glob('varmodel/*'):
        with open(dir) as f:
            varmodel = f.read(varmodel )
            # not sure about txt file content 
            # it may need preprocess before put to list
            all_files.append(varmodel )
    print(varmodel)
```